# How I can insert output of the cgi application in the html page?

Tags: html, c++, cgi

I write a program that will run `ps` command on the server, parse it and create an html page with table. Page should updates every 3 seconds, all that using cgi c++. So my question is which tag (if it exists) I could use in html file to run my cgi app, and paste the output (cgi returns html code). Example:

## index.html

```
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='3'>
<body>

<!-- Here I need to execute test.cgi and paste the output right here-->

</body>
</html>
```

## test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "<title> Hey </title> ";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is common gateway interface(cgi) here. If you are running Apache Webserver, you can easily make use of cgi. Just compile your c script (one way of doing it) into '.cgi' type of file, and place that in a place where you configure in httpd.conf to allow CGI execution. Make sure to give it 605 permission at least.

in C, I typically use

`printf("Content-Type: text/html\n\n");`

`printf(Followed by any HTTP Header I want to use including Refresh)`

Add the ps command inside your script and it probably would give you basic unformatted html page .. where your output would be shown on the top left of your browser. If you want a fully formatted page, that will require more work, but you don't need 2 files (1 cgi and 1 html) but instead only 1 cgi file.

Edit1: For Cpp, it should work similarly, so try applying what I said above.